# A concurrent Map (AtomicLongMap) of the greatest values constrained by size or automatic eviction

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, guava

I'm trying to maintain a map of keys to their respective elapsed time (long values). Guava's [AtomicLongMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html) works quite nicely for this with one issue: I only want to maintain largest values (elapsed time) so that the Map does not become ridiculous in size (there are large number of possible keys).

Thus I would like to ideally evict entries to maintain the map at a certain size. The largest values would be kept. Obviously I could do this in a blocking fashion (synchronized) but I'm looking for something less blocking as this map is accessed very very frequently by many threads.

One idea I have is to make a reaper that would run after a certain threshold has been hit, copy the map, trim and then reset the reference (probably an atomic reference or marked `volatile`). Of course this has many many down sides such has maintaining a separate thread and loosing data while the map is being copied along with I'm sure various other things that could go wrong.

Is there a data structure / library I should consider instead?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the map?  Why not just remove old entries in place? This sounds like you want to implement a moving window.  Perhaps a ring buffer with a binary search would be simpler.  You could use a ring buffer to delete entries when one is added in the current thread.

Comment: Keep a separate sorted data structure and use that to remove entries as needed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There was a reason and I'm forgetting why now. I suppose I was concerned with the map changing while doing it but it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is likely to add a concurrent ring buffer. When you add an entry, you get an entry to remove from the ring buffer. This way you are limited to the size of the ring buffer and you don't need an additional thread.

Comment: Except the ring buffer would have to maintain sort order by Map entry value, so that would make it a circular priority queue, no?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am assuming the order added is in chronological order, so no need to sort it.